# Existe algum SVN para banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, versionamento, replicação

Tenho o seguinte ambiente, um banco de dados (MySQL) online para produção e vários outros(cópias para cada desenvolvedor) usados para teste local.

Existe algum programa assim como o SVN que realize a cópia da estrutura sem os dados do banco?

Seria uma maneira de controlar as versões e alterações do banco de dados assim como também atualizar a estrutura dos *slaves*.

Como é este processo?

Comment: Existe, o SVN..

Comment: @Maniero Vc se refere a fazer o checkout da pasta data, onde ficam os dados do banco, isso? se for isso mesmo acredito que iria sobrepor os dados, isso pode prejudicar o ambiente local que já possui informação para teste.

Comment: só manter a estrutura? a ferramenta de export do Workbench não serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe, o SVN. Também pode usar o Git e outras ferramentas normais de versionamento. A estrutura do DB é expressa por um texto com um código que chamamos de [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) (Data Definition Language) onde o comando `CREATE TABLE` é o mais usado. Então você faz o versionamento como qualquer outro código. Note que só fará o controle das estruturas e não dos dados. Lembrando que copiar a estrutura sem os dados é tarefa do DBA e algo extremamente simples de fazer, não precisa de ferramenta, só saber usar o banco de dados que está usando.

Existem tecnologias usadas em conjunto com linguagens que possuem um mecanismo de *migration* e algumas podem ajudar no versionamento próprio.

Tem um [artigo do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html) sobre isto. Também tem um [*post* do Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/) que dá dicas para seguir. Outro [artigo interessante](https://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Collaboration/Database_Versioning/The_Concept_of_Database_Versioning).

Existem ferramentas específicas, mas em geral não são necessárias. Tem uma [lista delas](https://dbmstools.com/version-control-tools). Quando a pessoa não consegue se organizar elas acabam sendo úteis por fazer parte do trabalho.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero, esses artigos deram uma boa ajuda para entender melhor como fazer isso.